# Send email with Amazon SES in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, amazon-ses

I am looking for the best way of sending emails with Spring Integration using Amazon SES.

After some researching, I have found that an amazon Spring extension was being created for this purposes:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-aws/src/test/resources

But in SES's examples, I have seen that the namespace http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws is not available...

Is the project still alive or there is a better option?

Answer (score 1):

Spring finds dependent XSD schemas on the classpath - spring apps/extensions do not have to publish their schema on the internet; the namespace URI is a key used to locate the schema which, in this case is [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-extensions/blob/master/spring-integration-aws/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/aws/config/xml/spring-integration-aws-1.0.xsd).

The namespace mapping is [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-extensions/blob/master/spring-integration-aws/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.schemas).

Work continues on this extension project and I am sure the author (Amol) will welcome your feedback.

Using the extension does assume some prior knowledge of the [Spring Integration Project](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration/).

Comment: OK. I will contact him and let him know I am interested in the project. Thanks!